# Rails 4.1, email preview default route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm building application where I configured routes in following way:

1. first there is number of standard resoure routes
2. as a last route, I catch all other URLs using wildcard rule:

   get '*content_path' => 'content#content', as: :content

I would also like to use email preview functionality which generates URLs such as

```
http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/user_mailer/account_registration
```

Problem is that it seems like my "catch all" route catches everything including also email preview URLs which start with "/rails".

I would like to configure either my route to catch all URLs except those starting with "/rails" or configure rails default "/rails" route to take precedence over my "catch all" route.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution by using constraints in routes.rb file:

```
class RailsCoreConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    if request.original_fullpath.starts_with? "/rails"
      false
    else
      true
    end
  end
end
```